# Why does a parachute open up faster on Mars than on Earth?

Tags: planets, aerodynamics, drag

I recently heard that a parachute opens up much faster on Mars than on Earth. Why is that the case?

More specifically, during a NASA Edge TV program, one of the scientists working on parachute tests for capsules entering the atmosphere said that on Mars, parachutes open up in a fraction of the time necessary on Earth.

Comment: I hope you realize that the amount of time it takes a parachute to open up on Earth is not constant and is dependent of velocity, design of the chute, density of packing, etc. So, there's no way we can answer your question without more information. I guarantee that I could make you a parachute that opens up much faster than any have done on Mars. But that is meaningless if the conditions on my chute are radically different than the Martian ones

Comment: Could you provide a reference? Where did you hear this, and in what context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An identical parachute probably wouldn't (to a first approximation).

Terminal velocity is proportional to one over the square root of air density:
$$
v_t \propto\sqrt\frac{1}{\rho}
$$

and *very approximately* the time taken to fully deploy a parachute is proportional to the flux of particles hitting it:

$$
t_\text{deploy} \propto \rho v_t \propto \sqrt{\rho}
$$

The difference will be down to the design of the parachute.

Comment: Don't forget that you can begin opening a parachute on Mars at a much higher velocity than on Earth. An equivalent velocity on Earth to what is normal on Mars would burn up the chute (but I bet it'd open up faster than you could say "What are you doing!? Don't open that at these speeds!")

Comment: That is *sort of* factored in...!